# Dynamic cast specification (rule) clarification

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

We have the general form of dynamic_cast:

> dynamic_cast < new-type > ( expression )

I am specifically confused about the bold part of this rule (5a):

> 5: If expression is a pointer or reference to a polymorphic type Base,
> and new-type is a pointer or reference to the type Derived a run-time
> check is performed:
>
> a) The most derived object pointed/identified by expression is
> examined. If, in that object, expression points/refers to a public
> base of Derived, **and if only one object of Derived type is derived
> from the subobject pointed/identified by expression**, then the result
> of the cast points/refers to that Derived object. (This is known as a
> "downcast".)

Can you please give an example where this part would not be satisfied?

The above extract comes from cppreference: [cppreferenc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

Comment: You can construct examples using multiple inheritance, in which some bases AND classes derived from common bases are inherited more than once by some concrete class.   In that circumstance, the downcast from `Base` to `Derived` is ambiguous.

Comment: @YoungBajwa, good question, I think you should add to it that the extract is coming from cppreference and add the link as well

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi edited and added note & link, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fleshing out the multiple inheritance example @Peter summarized:

```
     Base1
     /   \  <-- Virtual inheritance here
  Base2  Base2
    |     | <-- Nonvirtual inheritance here and below
  Left   Right
    \     /
    Derived

Base1* p_base1 = new Derived();
Base2* p_base2 = dynamic_cast<Base2*>(p_base1); // Which Base2?
```

There are two different `Base2` objects within a `Derived` object, so which one should `p_base2` point to?

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base1 { virtual ~Base1() = default; };
struct Base2 : virtual Base1 { };
struct Left : Base2 { };
struct Right : Base2 { };
struct Derived : Left, Right {
    Derived() : Base1() {}
};

int main()
{
    Base1* p_base1 = new Derived();
    Base2* p_base2 = dynamic_cast<Base2*>(p_base1);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "p_base1 == nullptr: " << (p_base1 == nullptr) << '\n';
    std::cout << "p_base2 == nullptr: " << (p_base2 == nullptr);
    delete p_base1;
}
```

Trying to be a little careful here: `Base1` is inherited virtually so that there's only a single `Base1` subobject and we can actually initialize `p_base1`. However, `Derived` inherits nonvirtually from `Left` and `Right`, meaning that it has two instances of `Base2`. Therefore, the downcast fails.

Output:

```
p_base1 == nullptr: false
p_base2 == nullptr: true
```

Comment: Would this be resolved by using virtual inheritance?

Comment: Thanks for the example. I tried something similar before but dynamic_cast still succeeded hence the confusion. `Base1* p_base1 = new Derived();` results in compiler error as Derived* -> Base1* conversion is ambiguous.So, i took the Derived->Left->Base2->Base1 path to get a pointer to Base1 and then tried dynamic_cast and it works. https://godbolt.org/z/7ErE3M1av

Comment: @YoungBajwa You're correct that the answer as written doesn't let you write `Base1* p_base1 = new Derived();`, but changing it so that `Derived` inherits directly from `Base1` but there's still an ambiguity of which `Base2` it has causes the dynamic cast to fail.

Comment: The code example doesn't compile so I cannot replicate your output. https://godbolt.org/z/3z419eE93

Comment: Curious, I'm not sure why MSVC compiles it but GCC and Clang don't. It emits warnings but not errors.

Comment: Well, that is definitely a bug with MSVC. Derived* -> Base1* is ambiguous as there are three Base1 subobjects:
1) `Derived -> Base1`
2) `Derived -> Left -> Base2 -> Base1`
3) `Derived -> Right -> Base2 -> Base1`

Comment: The drawing appears to depict virtual inheritance. Regular inheritance is normally depicted as a tree.

Comment: It depicts multiple nonvirtual inheritance, which cannot be depicted as a tree. Anyway at this point I'm not sure how to construct a valid class hierarchy that would compile and still demonstrate the condition the question asks about.

Comment: @YoungBajwa: Fixed code on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/bfdG6o8rr